# Android - getting value from datepicker on a fragment/tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I have an activity with 3 tabs/fragments, one of them now has a datepicker which opens on a button click. The date picker works but im confused as to how i can get the selected date back on the fragment class to auto load some data after the change?

It's as if i need some sort of onDateSet but on the fragment class where my button click is.

Please advice if you can, thanks:

Fragment1/Tab1:

On btn click open the date picker:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bFromDate:
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                break;

        }
    }
```

DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment  extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    }
}
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the target fragment while instantiating your `DialogFragment` -

```
DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
picker.setTargetFragment(this, <request_code>); // any number
picker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

And in your `DialogFragment` whenever you want to send data back to the calling Fragment,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putStringExtra("key_date", formattedDate);
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), <request_code>, intent);
```

And in your receiving fragment, implement `onActivityResult()` to receive the data from the `DialogFragment`.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Make sure fragment codes match up 
    if (requestCode == <request_code>) {


      String date = data.getStringExtra("key_date");
...
}
```